# "Unable to download App... could not be installed at this time" - adobe phonegap build ios

Tags: ios, html, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm building an HTML5 app with phonegap and adobe phonegap build. I've gone through all the steps I believe are necessary to test my app on my device, but I'm still getting an error upon install from phone gap website:

```
"Unable to download App {app_name} could not be installed at this time".
```

I've gone through the following list to upload this app to phonegap:

1. Created a CSR file as per directions [here](http://brentsampson.com/2011/06/02/uploading-your-csr-file-to-the-apple-provisioning-portal/)
2. [Created an iOS developer certificate](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/signing_signing-ios.md.html) using the CSR file
3. Added a device to my developer profile by adding the UUID of my iPad [on the apple developer website](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/device/deviceList.action)
4. Created a development mobile provisioning file again on the [apple developer website](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/profileList.action)
5. Signed my app with p12 file and provisioning file on the adobe phonegap build website.

Can anyone spot anything I've missed? My app works with no problems when run on iOS emulator.

Hopefully this question can serve as a guide for others, it seems to be a fairly lengthy process to get this sorted.

Comment: Did you sign it with a developing profile or distribution profile, I beleive for adhoc distribution we need a distribution profile , One another SOlution to this problem would be to re-upload the build, It might not have been uploaded properly

Comment: Yep, phonegap enforces this, you have to upload the provisioning file with the p12 file.

Comment: try uploading the build once again

Comment: I re-built, same result sadly.

Comment: then its a problem with either your distribution profile or phonegap server

Comment: I'll look at the provisioning file again and check the UUID.

Comment: Do you know if the UUID is case sensitive? I typed as I saw it (all upper case), but it's been changed to lower case on the developer.apple.com

Comment: yes it may be so, better use UDID as it is shown in the itunes screenwhen you connect your device..while we are on it do not trust any third party apps to get UDID, I had done it once and it resulted in bogus UDID's

Comment: Yes I made that mistake originally too. Still, I didn't put it in lower case, seems as if apple changes it when you upload.

Comment: I got it working! It was that app that you talked about, although I spotted that it had give the wrong UUID, after uploading the correct one I mistakenly selected the old one. Apple should give the facility to remove UUIDs before the year's subscription is over. Thanks for your help. Post an answer if want to :)

Comment: apple does gives an option to remove the Unused UDID, once when you renew it, then for the first time ehen you got to devices screen it will ask you to edit it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the UDID included in your provisioning Profile, if it is same as that of your device being displayed in iTunes, UDID is a very secure property of your iDevice, kindly do not trust any  third party apps other then itunes for accessing the UDID of iDevices